# Does an ipad (iOS) need to be restarted occasionally?

Tags: ios, ipad

Most of our webapp users never restart their ipads. (They think they are but they are just putting them to sleep).

Does the iPad reclaim memory, storage, etc. from apps that were never closed? Would restarting it fix this?

Symptoms this might fix:

- Audio is distorted
- Video is partially black

Comment: by no means any kind of absolute - but I restart my phone like I restart my Mac, every OS update; or if I suspect something 'weird'. So, uptime measured in months, not days.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to try and restart my iPhone/iPad every few weeks or once a month. I've found it to be a good best practice. If nothing else it just gives you a clean slate to begin on again! I hope this helps you out!

Comment: These conclusions are based on what? Most of the people never doing this, unless the iPad/iPhone discharged totally, they don't even know how to do this :)

Comment: @Farside I've ran into issues at least with my iPhone where things start to run strangely and even closing all applications doesn't help things. Because of that I tend to need to restart my iPhone which solve the issue. I have a standard iPhone 6 and I have had to do this since I got it. If most people don't run into this problem then that's ok too. But that has been my experience over the life of this phone. Back when I used my iPad a lot more than I do now I would have the same issue. I didn't restart it all the time, but monthly or around there tended to help the problem.

Comment: @Farside I'd say these conclusions are based on experiences of the person. What kinda of evidence do you need?

Comment: @chillie, i dont mind about private opinion... But the answer have to bring the information, some facts, actions to reboot, references or some evidence... not just opinion based thing or chatty answers. It could be posted as comment, but not full-fledged answer. You know what I mean.

Comment: It's not an opinion when someone says that there phone was acting funny, they rebooted it and it started working correctly again. I would call that facts, and a full-fledged answer.